# What does the pronoun "they" refer to in this sentence "in how many ways can they select the host for these championships"

Tags: pronouns, subjects

I am reading a textbook on statistics.

There is confusion about a paragraph in an exercise.

> If the NCAA has applications from six universities for hosting its intercollegiate tennis championships in 1998 and 1999, in how many ways can **they** select the host for these championships
>
> (a)
>   if **they** are not both to be held at the same university;
>
> (b)
>   if **they** may both be held at the same university?

The pronoun "**they**" appears three times.

The second and third "**they**" refer to "these two championships".

But I am not sure what subject the first "**they**" refers to.

Does the first "**they**" refer to "six universities"or "applicarions"?

Comment: The first **they** would appear to refer to the NCAA in its role as the selector of the host for the championships, while the second and third **theys** refer to the championships themselves.

Comment: But there is a pronoun "its". What does the pronoun "its" refer to?

Comment: **Its** appears to refer to the NCAA. That's to say, the *intercollegiate tennis championships **of** the NCAA.

Comment: Why do two pronouns "they" and "its"  both refer to the same "The NCAA"? Is this a way better than "they" and "their"?

Comment: The answer below picks up this point. That aside, native English speakers and writers frequently mix up their **its** and **they/their** in the same sentence. Radio and TV reporters and commentators are prime suspects. The fault is similar to the typical: **One** knows what's right but **you** can't help doing something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pronouns **they** and **its** both refer to NCAA, an association.

If I had to guess why **its** was used with **its championships** and **they** was used with the verb **select**, it's because "to select" is an action that requires human deliberation whereas the entity, the association, can lend its name to a "championship".  Not to imply that this is any sort of grammatical rule; I'm just speculating on what might have been going on in the author's mind. Some speakers would be uncomfortable saying "In how many ways can **it select**..." or would be thinking of the people on the selection committee making the decision.

Comment: Using _they_ for a collective entity in this way is normal in British English, but frowned on in American. I suspect that purists even in Britain would object ot _its_ when _they_ is being used of the same object; but Tᴚoɯɐuo exlanation of why it happens seems a good one to me.

Comment: Is it possible that "its" refers to "the host"?

Comment: @user9418: Not in this particular instance with the NCAA (since individual universities do not have any claim of possession on an intercollegiate tennis championship) but  so-called *cataphoric* reference is possible. You could say *The veterinarian considers its weight when determining the vaccine dosage a dog should receive*, and there **its** would refer to **a dog**.

Comment: Really appreciate your clear answers.